# Select the records with max count from a SQL result set

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where at the moment there are customers with `customerId` and `filePath` column but there were no restrictions so there might be several record for the same customer containing different filepaths. The goal of the script that I'm trying to write is to get a result containing `customerId` and `filePath` where the `filePath` is the one used mostly for this customer (Count(filePath) is biggest) so that each record from the result contains unique `customerId`s in the first column and in the second column the value of the `filePath` which has most records associated with this customer.

So what I have till now is this:

```
SELECT customerId, localFilePath, Count(customerId) as Count1 
FROM CustomerDetails
GROUP BY localFilePath, customerId
```

which returns this:

```
CustomerId LocalFilePath Count1
3          AnotherFilePath  1
3          localFilePath    3
11         localFilePath    1
331        localFilePath    1
2414       localFilePath    3
2527       localFilePath    1
2528       localFilePath    1
2533       localFilePath    1
2535       localFilePath    1
```

Where currently only customer with id 3 has more than one value but no matter if there is one or many user as in this case I want to return the results for the rest of the users since they don't have several filepaths but I want to retrun the row where `Count1 = 3` for the customer with `customerId = 3` as shown in the result.

EDIT

The expected result is:

```
CustomerId LocalFilePath Count1
3          localFilePath    3
11         localFilePath    1
331        localFilePath    1
2414       localFilePath    3
2527       localFilePath    1
2528       localFilePath    1
2533       localFilePath    1
2535       localFilePath    1
```

The idea is that all unique customerIds must stay, and records which have the same customerId should be filtered so it lefts only one record with this customerId which has the higher value in the `Count1` column

Comment: Can you please post the expected result

Comment: CustomerID 2414 also has `Count1 = 3`. Shouldn't that be included as well?

Comment: @ZoffDino See edit pls

Comment: You could either create a column in the table to hold the count results and then select max count from that or you could add WHERE count(CustomerID) > 1 to your code.

Comment: In fact if you just temp tabled the result set and ask for the max(count1) it'd work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
;WITH
    cte AS  
    (
        SELECT customerId, localFilePath, Count(customerId) as Count1 
        FROM CustomerDetails
        GROUP BY localFilePath, customerId
    )

SELECT  customerid, localFilePath, Count1
FROM    (
            SELECT  customerid, localFilePath, Count1,
                    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY Count1 DESC)
            FROM    cte
        ) temp
WHERE   temp.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but isn't there a way to make it without using `CTE`? I forgot to mention that my target version is `MS SQL SERVER 2014` and I thought there would be something else.. Still this is correct and if there is no answer reflecting newer versions I will accept it.

Comment: @Leron yes, you can do it with a CTE. Just replace `FROM cte` with `FROM (your original query)`

Comment: What is your concern about using a CTE? Do you also have a need to avoid `row_number()`? And by the way, you might have a problem with ties.

Comment: @shawnt00 It's just that I don't feel very comfortable with more complex operations in `SQL` and using `CTE` at least for me is one of them. Of course the obvious answer is just to learn, but my overall direction is to develop as a `C#` programmer. It would be very interesting conversation to what extend someone who is spending most of his time coding in language `X` should be familiar and fluent with `SQL` but for the comment section that's the way I can sum it up.

Comment: Think of a CTE as having some of the benefits of a function. It has a name and it's reusable. (It might also work to think of it as a macro.) There are solutions that don't involve `row_number` (analytic functions seem more complicated to me) but you can't get rid of the query nesting in some form unless you used temp tables.

Answer (score 2):

The analytic functions are helpful for your situation. This query will rank the location counts by customer:

```
SELECT
  localFilePath,
  RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY customerId
    ORDER BY Count1 DESC) AS CountRank
FROM (
  SELECT customerId, localFilePath, COUNT(*) AS Count1
  FROM CustomerDetails
  GROUP BY customerId, localFilePath
) InitCalc
```

The most-used locations per customer will have a `CountRank` value of 1. To limit results to rows where `CountRank = 1` you have to wrap the query again:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    localFilePath,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY customerId
      ORDER BY Count1 DESC) AS CountRank
  FROM (
    SELECT customerId, localFilePath, COUNT(*) AS Count1
    FROM CustomerDetails
    GROUP BY customerId, localFilePath
  ) InitCalc
) CountCalc
WHERE CountRank = 1
```

If there's a tie for the most-used location for a customer, the query above will return all of the first-place records for each customer. If you want only one location per customer, change `RANK()` to `ROW_NUMBER()` but note that this will arbitrarily pick a winner from the tied values.

Comment: Thanks, another very proficient answer. I just feel that this query is overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. Do you think there is a way to get advantage of the fact that I can use all features of `SQL SERVER 2014` and simplify this? As for the tie cases, random choice is just fine.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're ranking an aggregate, which pretty much forces a subquery or a CTE, then you're filtering an analytic value, which forces yet another subquery. If I remember correctly, 2014 added little or nothing to the SQL syntax. Teradata has a `QUALIFY` keyword which would let you filter on the `RANK` result without the additional subquery, but 2014 definitely doesn't have it, though [a lot of people are asking for it](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/532474).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
with cte as
(
SELECT customerID, localFilePath, Count(customerID) as Count1 
FROM CustomerDetails
GROUP BY localFilePath, customerID
)
,
cte1
as
(select customerID,max(Count1) as count2 from cte group by customerID)
select cte.customerid,cte.localfilepath,cte.count1 from cte inner join
cte1 on cte.customerid=cte1.customerid and cte.count1=cte1.count2 order by
customerid
```

Now, if (for example) the two counts for ID 3 were the same, i.e. you had two more rows in the customerdetails table for "AnotherFilePath" then this would produce two rows for ID 3 and then you would have to decide on a criterion for which one to select. IS THIS IMPORTANT? Do you have a way of deciding between filepaths if any ID has the *same number* of filepaths logged?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
-- create table variable
DECLARE @Table TABLE( 
  id int,
  filePath varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  Count1 int
); 

INSERT INTO @Table 
SELECT customerId, localFilePath, Count(customerId) as Count1 
FROM CustomerDetails
GROUP BY localFilePath, customerId

-- Then select the max
SELECT m.id, m.MaxCount, (SELECT Top 1 filePath from @Table where id = m.id and Count1 = m.MaxCount) as ThePath
FROM (
    SELECT t.id, MAX(t.Count1) as MaxCount
    FROM @Table t
    GROUP BY t.id
) m
```

Which results in:

```
id      MaxCount    ThePath
3       3           localFilePath
11      1           localFilePath
331     1           localFilePath
2414    3           localFilePath
2527    1           localFilePath
2528    1           localFilePath
2533    1           localFilePath
2535    1           localFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

Without CTE:

```
SELECT top 1 customerId, localFilePath, Count(customerId) as Count1 
FROM CustomerDetails
GROUP BY localFilePath, customerId
order by Count(customerId) desc
```